# iOS-Universal-Framework installation problems

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, osx-elcapitan, telegram

I try to install [iOS-Universal-Framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework). Try to run [instalation shell screept](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework/blob/master/Real%20Framework/install.sh) from this repository and all time get message:

```
iOS Real Static Framework Installer
===================================

This will install the iOS static framework templates and support files on your computer.
Note: Real static frameworks require two xcspec files to be added to Xcode.

*** THIS SCRIPT WILL ADD THE FOLLOWING FILES TO XCODE ***

 * Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/UFW-iOSStaticFramework.xcspec
 * Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/UFW-iOSStaticFramework.xcspec

Where is Xcode installed? (CTRL-C to abort) [ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer ]: 
Could not find Xcode files in "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer". Please make sure you typed it correctly.
You should see the path "Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications" inside of it.

Where is Xcode installed? (CTRL-C to abort) [ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer ]:
```

So I press enter because I have success installed xCode. But all time get message:

```
Where is Xcode installed? (CTRL-C to abort) [ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer ]: 
Could not find Xcode files in "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer". Please make sure you typed it correctly.
You should see the path "Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications" inside of it.
```

I tried to check if xCode has correct installed:

```
xcode-select -p
```

And get message:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

After this I try to install command line tools (before that I hadn't it):

```
gcc -v
```

and get message:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

So command line tools should work well. But I cannot finish installation to Universal-Framework.

PS: All this stuff I do because I want to launch [Telegram test project](https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram)

Comment: did you found any solution for this? I am facing the same error.

Comment: As an alternative solution for similar cases: https://github.com/gurhub/universal-framework

Answer (score 0):

You need to add folder Specification in Xcode sources:
Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode
Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode